OpenVPN 3 Service Fails to Start After Update on Ubuntu
I use Ubuntu and OpenVPN 3, which I previously installed and used successfully with the GNOME GUI. However, after a system update and deleting some unused files (including AnyConnect VPN-related files), OpenVPN 3 stopped working.
When I attempt to start the OpenVPN 3 session using the command:
sudo systemctl enable --now openvpn3-session@CloudConnexa.service
I receive the following error:
Job for openvpn3-session@CloudConnexa.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration. Result: protocol.  

What I’ve Tried:

Confirmed the configuration files (.ovpn) are correct and free of errors.
Reinstalled OpenVPN 3 multiple times (tried different versions as well).
Followed the official documentation for setup and configuration.

Context:

OpenVPN 3 was working fine before the update.
The error started appearing after deleting unused VPN-related files.

Question:
What should be my next steps to diagnose and resolve this issue? Are there any specific logs or configuration checks I might have missed?
